# Composer not loading 'dev-master' versions from cache

Tags: php, composer-php

I have two projects `yiisoft/yii2-app-basic` and `yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced` that I installed approximately 10 minutes apart using composer. I noticed that in the second one all dependencies with `dev-master` as the 'version' were downloaded afresh despite the fact that the dependency information was identical e.g:

```
Installing yiisoft/yii2 (dev-master a946a0a)
Cloning a946a0a212625d0cf655e947c835e8d6d28dd2d7
```

This seems kind of wasteful so is this by design? If so why? Lastly, if possible, how can I make it install `dev-master` versions from cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When requiring branches, Composer does clone the repository by default. Because Composer does not keep a repository in the cache, it has to be cloned twice.

If you want to not clone, but download something, then you can run `composer update --prefer-dist`, and Composer will try to download released ZIPs if possible. Projects being hosted on Github and Bitbucket offer to also download any commit from a repository, so this would be used in these cases. The download will then be cached and reused.

Note that cloning a repository once will probably be faster if you run updates later because the download of a small diff is less data than downloading an entire new ZIP file with almost all files inside unaltered.

Switching from one download method to the other requires the vendor folder and the `composer.lock` file to be deleted, AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks. I ran the `composer install --prefer-dist` for two fresh installations of the above projects. The message changed from `cloning` to `downloading` and the second installation was loaded from cache. The first install was also markedly faster.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same problem lately - the problem was that composer.lock which locks certain commit of given package. Deleting of composer.lock fixed the problem for me.